# Caching OVERLAPPED structures when using IOCPs in Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, sockets, atomic, iocp

I'm using I/O Completion Ports in Windows, I have an object called 'Stream' that resembles and abstract an HANDLE (so it can be a socket, a file, and so on).

When I call Stream::read() or Stream::write() (so, ReadFile()/WriteFile() in the case of files, and WSARecv()/WSASend() in the case of sockets), I allocate a new OVERLAPPED structure in order to make a pending I/O request that will be completed in the IOCP loop by some other thread.

Then, when the OVERLAPPED structure will be completed by the IOCP loop, it will be destroyed there. If that's the case, Stream::read() or Stream::write() are called again from the IOCP loop, they will instance new OVERLAPPED structures, and it will go forever.

This works just fine. But now I want to improve this by adding caching of OVERLAPPED objects:
when my Stream object does a lot of reads or writes, it absolutely makes sense to cache the OVERLAPPED structures.

But now arise a problem: when I deallocate a Stream object, I must deallocate the cached OVERLAPPED structures, but how I can know if they've been completed or are still pending and one of the IOCP loops will complete that lately? So, an *atomic* reference count is needed here, but now the problem is that if I use an atomic ref counter, I have to increase that ref counter for each read or write operations, and decrease on each IOCP loop completion of the OVERLAPPED structure or Stream deletion, which in a server are *a lot* of operations, so I'll end up by increasing/decreasing *a lot* of atomic counters *a lot* of times.

Will this impact very negatively the concurrency of multiple threads? This is my only concern that blocks me to put this atomic reference counter for each OVERLAPPED structure.

Are my concerns baseless?

I thought this is an important topic to point out, and a question on SO, to see other's people thoughts on this and methods for caching OVERLAPPED structures with IOCP, is worth it.
I wish to find out a clever solution on this, without using atomic ref counters, if it is possible.

Comment: You are fretting over nanoseconds when the operation takes milliseconds.  That strongly fits the "root of all evil" mantra.

Comment: 'Then, when the OVERLAPPED structure will be completed by the IOCP loop, it will be destroyed there.' - why are you destroying it? It should either a member of the stream class or of some other 'IOCPbuffer' class that is cached and used in the WSA calls and whose data is applied to its stream upon IOCP completion before being released back to its pool.

Comment: Martin, yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve, and I want to know if an atomic ref counter is ok to be used for those 'IOCPbuffer' structures. Hans, the problem is not nanoseconds or milliseconds, but its about locking, a bunch of LOCKed instructions can affect thread concurrency, since when a region of memory (e.g. the atomic counter) is atomically read/written, other cores must wait the completion of the atomic transaction.

Comment: AFAIK, you do not need any atomic counter.  If you are cacheing/pooling those instances, you never destroy them, just repool them.  The pool iself would require a lock, but the time spent on handling the lock would surely be swamped by the avoidance of continual creation/destruction of the class instances.

Comment: Oh.. hang on, are you sending the same buffer to multiple clients?  Is that why you need the refCount?

Comment: No, if I allocate a new i/o packet, that is IOCPbuffer structure, I will keep a pointer of it inside the Stream object, then I'll call ReadFile or WSARecv and I get ERROR_IO_PENDING: the packet is pending. Now: if I call Stream::close() which in turn will call CloseHandle(handle); another thread will complete the pending read, but the question is: where I must deallocate the packet? in the IOCP loop, or in the Stream's dtor, since the Stream object has a pointer to that packet, so shares its ownership? An atomic counter would solve this threadsafely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you bundle a data buffer with the `OVERLAPPED` structure as a 'per operation' data object then pooling them to avoid excessive allocation/deallocation and heap fragmentation is a good idea.

If you only ever use this object for I/O operations then there's no need for a ref count, simply pull one from the pool, do your WSASend/WSARecv with it and then release it to the pool once you're done with it in the IOCP completion handler.

If, however, you want to get a bit more complicated and allow these buffers to be passed out to other code then you may want to consider ref counting them if that makes it easier. I do this in my current framework and it allows me to have generic code for the networking side of things and then pass data buffers from read completions out to customer code and they can do what they want with them and when they're done they release them back to the pool. This currently uses a ref count but I'm moving away from that as a minor performance tweak. The ref count is still there but in most situations it only ever goes from 0 -> 1 and then to 0 again, rather than being manipulated at various layers within my framework (this is done by passing the ownership of the buffer out to the user code using a smart pointer).

In most situations I expect that a ref count is unlikely to be your most expensive operation (even on NUMA hardware in situations where your buffers are being used from multiple nodes). More likely the locking involved in putting these things back into a pool will be your bottleneck; I've solved that one so am moving on to the next higher fruit ;)

You also talk about your 'per connection' object and caching your 'per operation' data locally there (which is what I do before pushing them back to the allocator), whilst ref counts aren't strictly required for the 'per operation' data, the 'per connection' data needs, at least, an atomically modifiable 'num operations in progress' count so that you can tell when you can free IT up. Again, due to my framework design, this has become a normal ref count for which customer code can hold refs as well as active I/O operations. I've yet to work a way around the need for this counter in a general purpose framework.

Comment: Thanks Len. Well, I have a general purpose framework here, so I don't need to expose io requests packets to the user, instead I want to hide them. With the normal design of (A) taking an io req. packet from a pool and (B) put it back on the pool from the iocp handler thread would indeed brings a new bottleneck: the locking of the pool. My aim here is to keep the same io req. packet, until the life of the connection, so until the life of the Stream object. Now the only concern I have is *when* I have to deallocate the io req. packet, inside Stream's dtor, or inside iocp handler?

Comment: If the packet is pending, I'll do that on the iocp handler, if its not pending anymore, and not used anymore, I must deallocate it from the Stream's dtor, or it will leak a packet. Now the problem is that I don't know if I need some atomic counter (or even a boleean value) which simply tells me *atomically* that the packet is not pending anymore, no other threads has any kind of ownership on it, so I can delete it from Stream's dtor. Someone say that I do not need atomicity here, but is that true? I'm a bit doubtful here.

Comment: Assuming you never deallocate your stream until all operations issued on it have completed then you don't need a counter in the per operation data but, you will, likely, need a counter in your stream to track operations in progress.

Comment: I indeed never deallocate the stream until all operations pending are completed. Since I do only 1 operation each time, I have 2 flags: pending read, and pending write, so when i have 00==no pending operations, 11==pending both write and reading, 01==pending read, and so on. I set the flag on before calling ReadFile() and I set it off in the iocp handler. Here I don't need atomic flags, nor atomic counters because I perform only 1 operation, correct?